# getResourceAsStream filepath while running .jar

Tags: java, jar, inputstream, filepath

My code:

```
BufferedInputStream bis =
  new BufferedInputStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream("playerhit.mp3"));
```

This code works fine when the `playerhit.mp3` file is in same package as the `MP3.class`it is running in. I'm running this as .jar. If though I change the file path to something like `/src/data/audio/playerhit.mp3` it doesn't work anymore. Is there anyway to access different filepath than root of the package while running as .jar?

Comment: Is the `playerhit.mp3` copied to your classpath during the build? What do you use to build: Ant, Maven, ...?

Comment: I don't think so... and I'm using netbeans to build.

Comment: Did you use "data/audio/playerhit.mp3"  instead of "playerhit.mp3" ?

Comment: Yes I did use that path

Comment: What happens when you put that path in getResourceAsStream() ?

Comment: it works through netbeans but not when running from .jar

Answer (score 10):

Take a look at the [Javadoc for `getResourceAsStream(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29).

If the argument begins with a `/`, then the absolute name of the resource is the portion of the name following the `/`. Otherwise, the absolute name is of the following form:
`modified_package_name/name`
Where the `modified_package_name` is the package name of this object with `/` substituted for `.`.

So, if your `playerhit.mp3` is in the root of your package structure, you should reference it as `/playerhit.mp3`. If it's in `/src/data/audio/`, you should probably use `/data/audio/playerhit.mp3` - but check the contents of your JAR file to be sure.

Comment: It is /data/audio/playerhit.mp3. I tried using "/data/audio/" which doesn't work even running straight from netbeans and "./data/audio" works otherwive but not when running from .jar

Comment: Is the `data` folder on your classpath in Netbeans? The `getResourceAsStream()` method only loads resources that are on the classpath.

Comment: Ok now i feel stupid. After using path as just "data/audio/filename.mp3" without slash or dot I got it to work. Cheers guys, hope this at least helps others

Answer (score 0):

Check first if the file is actually in the jar.

Check the location inside the jar.

Relative path: current package

Absolute path: root of jar