# create executable jar file with text file

Tags: java, jar, export, embedded-resource, executable-jar

I have a java project this project has a text file to read from. i want to export a excuteable jar file . 
i did it but when i run the program on cmd window it says that the file couldnt be found.

How to export the whole project inclusive the text file ? or should i place the file in another place

```
scn = new Scanner(new File("src/test.txt"));
    while(scn.hasNext())
    {
        String instructionLine = scn.next();
        li.add(instructionLine) ;

    }

    scn.close();

}
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.print("File couldnt found !");
    }
```

Comment: An embedded resource can not be accessed by `File`, instead use an `URL`.

Comment: Also, the path will probably need a leading `/`

Comment: you must give full path where your jar running..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use getResourceAsStream() to get data from within your jar file.

See this "[prior answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16010539/getresourceasstream-filepath-while-running-jar)".