# getResource() unable to read contents of a directory inside jar

Tags: java, jar

I just came around this issue that the main class inside jar is unable to read the contents of a folder.
The class contains

```
String path = "flowers/FL8-4_zpsd8919dcc.jpg";
    try {
        File file = new File(TestResources.class.getClassLoader()
                                .getResource(path).getPath());
        System.out.println(file.exists());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here sysout returns `false`.

But when I try something like this it works

```
    String path = "flowers/FL8-4_zpsd8919dcc.jpg";
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = TestResources.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path);
        byte bytes[] = new byte[is.available()];
        is.read(bytes);
        out = new FileOutputStream("abc.jpg");
        out.write(bytes);
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

`getResourceAsStream()` is able to read the path of the folder inside jar but `getResource()` is unable to read it,

why is it so and what is the difference between the reading mechanism of these two methods for contents inside jar.
The contents of the simple jar

[image]

Comment: Could you try with `/flowers/FL8-4_zpsd8919dcc.jpg`?

Comment: @sp00m still nullpointer

Comment: `java.io.File` is for referencing artefacts on the file system. Individual JAR entries are not visible to the file system.

Comment: is there a way to read the files of the folder inside the jar and create an array out of it

Answer (score 2):

Both `getResource()` and `getResourceAsStream()` are able to find resources in jar, they use the same mechanism to locate resources.

But when you construct a `File` from an `URL` which denotes an entry inside a jar, `File.exists()` will return `false`. `File` cannot be used to check if files inside a jar/zip exists.

You can only use `File.exists` which are on the local file system (or attached to the local file system).

Comment: then suppose i need the files inside the folder which is inside the jar how to get it without using `JarFile` class.

Comment: What do you mean by "get it"? Read its content into a byte array? Or get an `InputStream` which reads its content?

Comment: well I need the files of that folder inside the jar and create and array of files with it

Comment: `File` cannot describe jar entries, you should not use it for that. Instead use `URL`s which can, and you can get their content by `URL.openStream()` which works fine both for files and jar/zip entries.

Comment: The scenario here is I need the files inside the folder so that i can use them for some other task I cannot use inputstream  so any way to do it

Comment: If you really need `File`s, you can't pack them and use them from a jar file.

Comment: so the only thing I can do in this case is read the file from outside the jar right?

Comment: Yes, if you need `File` and nothing else is accepted, you must not pack them or unpack them before use.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [an absolute path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16010539/getresourceasstream-filepath-while-running-jar) to get the behavior you're expecting, e.g. `/flowers/FL8-4_zpsd8919dcc.jpg`, as sp00m suggested.